# JetBrains directory tree configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, config, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using [babel-root-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-root-import) NPM plugin, but I have trouble with IntelliJ IDEA. Unfortunately, this IDE did not recognize `~/` signature, and did not resolve path to local files files. Is it possible to customize IntelliJ IDEA for this purpose?

**P.S.** Idea works perfectly with this path:

```
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent';
```

But not work with

```
import MyComponent from '~/components/MyComponent';
```

This path should be interpreted as `C:/project/src/components/MyComponent`. So, is it possible to interpret `~/` as `C:/project/src/`?

(project configured properly, I can deploy it, problem is only with IntelliJ IDEA config).

Comment: Added `webstorm` tag as the problem is linked to web technologies (so would affect that IDE as well) -- should increase the chance for this question to be noticed by the right person.

Comment: Are you using webpack by any chance? This `~/` seem to be used often there. I mean https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21999 --> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13409 -- not sure how relevant it is though (not a JS person myself).

Comment: webpack modules resolving (including http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) can be expected in 2017.2. But we have no plans to support babel-root-import rootPathPrefix/suffix: we can't afford providing special support for each and every module found on the web

Comment: I'm using gulp and babel. Anyway, I want to try webpack modules resolving, possibly it will work with my config.

Comment: As I understand, it's not implemented yet in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13409. I was little confused, veacause @lena said it can be expected in 2017.2, and 2017.4 already available for download.

Comment: 2017.1.4 is available, 2017.2 is not yet released